# ios webcal request - completion callback?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, webcal

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"valid_webcal_url"];
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
{
    // failure callback
    NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:LCHLocalizedString(@"SUBSCRIBE_ERROR", nil) message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

So I've figured out how to see if there was an error loading the webcal, but how can I know when the webcal was loaded successfully? I display a loader when the "subscribe" button is tapped and just need to know when to turn it off.

Comment: Why are you raping poor `NSLog()`? Format strings can contain constant parts, and `NSLog(@"Failed to open url: %@", url);` is **much more readable.**

Comment: Doesn't openURL put your app in the background anyway?

Comment: Apparently when using the webcal protocol it does not. Funky, I know but your comment helped me find a workable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is using `openURL` to retrieve an item using the webcal protocol, there is no visual separation of app and webcal retrieval.

What I'm having to do is listen for the notification `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` after calling `openURL` and when the notification is fired I assume it's the webcal taking over from my openURL call.

This is tricky business and a rudimentary fix but hey, it works! Thanks for all help/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments this will put your app in the background with no guaranteed means to automatic return.

Assuming you actually want to invoke a web page (as opposed to doing a web api call) you should probably create a custom subclass of `UIViewController` with an embedded `UIWebView`.

Setting your subclass as a delegate of the `UIWebView` will allow you to react to failure/success. You can even intercept and stop `UIWebView` calls with `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`